# Zener V-I and V-T dependence

Tags: zener

It's known that forward drop of diodes has exponential V-I dependence, and -2mv/°C V-T dependence. But what about reverse drop of Zener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good datasheet will cover both tempco (at different currents, for different Zener voltages) and voltage vs. current characteristics for different nominal Zener voltages.

There are considerable differences in behavior depending on the zener voltage. For example, [this](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/1N5333B-D.PDF) datasheet has the following graphs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For reverse voltage operation, there are two effects, the Zener effect and the avalanche effect. Each effect behaves differently vs. temperature. This is explained in the Wikipedia entry, under 'Operation'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode